# Aligning a fixed size block and a responsive block side by side?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a 900px wide centered table with one row and two cells.
I want the right cell to always be 200px wide and the left cell should fill out the rest, but when I make the browser window smaller the right cell jumps down under the left cell.
(when both cells have percentages it works fine but the right cell/block needs to be 200px)?

My HTML:

```
<table class="sitecontent">
  <tr>
    <td class="boxed"> contents </td>
    <td class="infobar"> contents </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

My CSS:

```
.sitecontent {
   max-width:900px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   display: table;
   height: 100%; 
}

.boxed {
   max-width:75%;
   float: left;    
}

.infobar {   
   float: left;
   width: 200px;
   border: 1px solid rgb(240,240,240);
   overflow: auto;
   max-height: 100%;
}
```

Shouldn't the max-width make the width of "boxed" less than 75% so that the content fits when the table width goes below 900px?

I've tried using divs instead of a table, but the result is the same?

Comment: Why are you floating table cells?

Comment: It's leftover code from when trying to align with divs instead of table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the other cell to fill out the rest of the space you can use a function called calc()

This allows you to determine sizes using basic addition and subtraction using percentages and fixed units.

calc() is widely supported see http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

One good reference is http://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/

In the following example I have

```
.boxed {
    max-width:calc(100% - 200px);   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AuroraArcade/42g5mw80/2/

In order to make the infobar 200px wide you either have to use box-sizing:border-box on the element or you can adjust the inner width or you can remove the borders and spacing.

One example

```
.infobar {   
   width: 200px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border: 1px solid rgb(240,240,240);
   overflow: auto;
   max-height: 100%;
}
```